# How to modify view controller created by storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have created a tabbed application in Xcode 5 by using storyboard with 5 different tabs.

Now I want to access the fifth view controller to pragmatically modify some fields, so i wish to access the view controller automatically created by the storyboard.

I have given the view controller a identifier and in my viewDidLoad method, i have used following codes

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [self storyboard];
ProfileViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"loginviewcontroller"];
[controller setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDefault];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but apparently a new view controller is created and presented on the top of original view controller instance which is created by storyboard automatically, and the tab bar navigation also disappears.

How shall access that view controller created by storyboard automatically or this is the wrong approach? If this is the wrong approach, how shall I achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access it through your tab bar controller. From any controller embedded in the tab bar controller you can get a reference like this:

```
UIViewController *controller = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[4];
```

To set the fields, instead of trying to set them from another controller, just pass the data that the #5 controller needs to do that itself. Since the view of #5 won't have been loaded until it's viewed the first time, you can't modify its view from another controller. So, in ProfileViewController, create and integer property, lets call it fieldValues, and pass the data to it. In the controller where you want to pass the information:

```
ProfileViewController *controller = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[4];
controller.fieldValues = PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDefault;
```

Then in viewDiLoad of ProfileViewController, do this:

```
[self setFields:self.fieldValue];
```

Comment: hi i have followed this approach to access the view controller, but strangely i couldn't change the view from that view controller. (not reflected on simulator). is there any extra step i need to perform?

Comment: @Bob, probably because that controllers view hasn't been loaded yet. When a tab bar controller is instantiated, all its content controllers are also instantiated, but only the controller in the first tab has its viewDidLoad called. You can pass data to controller #5, and have it change its view in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Bob, I've edited my answer to show you what I mean by passing the data.

Comment: I tried your code above, but it gave me error msg of "property 'fieldValue' not found on object of type 'ProfileViewController *'". But instead, I put the two lines code "ProfileViewController *controller = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[4];[controller setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDefault];" under the ViewDidLoad method of my first tab, and it just works -- it changes the fields of my fifth tab view. Any idea why this happens? PS:I am using parse framework as you probably notice.

Comment: @Bob, you got that error because you didn't add that property to the .h file of ProfileViewController. I'm not familiar with Parse, but it must be that fields is just a property of the controller, so you can set it from outside (that is, it's not setting the value of a UI element, but a property instead, which is what I was trying to do with my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't present your view controller, because your view controller is already a part of your tabbar. So select it using the following code:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:yourIndex];
```

Your code would be like this:

```
UIViewController *controller = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[4];
[controller setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsDefault];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: hi it looks promising but when i try this the "view" is not updated. as you can see i am trying to add in the "PFLogInFieldsFacebook" field to the "view" but the field is not shown. :( is there any idea regarding why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Documentation
regarding instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

`You use this method to create view controller objects that you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier string in Interface Builder.`

Comment: You cannot assign as NSString("loginviewcontroller") to an tag (NSInteger) value

Comment: hi i am confused, it says "tag it with an appropriate identifier string", but why shall i give it a NSInteger value?